# I am trying to downlad a file from a webserver using ftp in android

Tags: android, ftp-client

My Below code is not working, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am trying to download a file from my ftp server, however my code is not working and also not giving me any error.

```
  private Boolean downloadAndSaveFile(String server, int portNumber,
                                                    String user, String password, Strinenter code hereg filename, File localFile)
                        throws IOException {
                    FTPClient ftp = null;
                    String remoteFile1 = "/public_html/46.jpg";// path of a file which is on a web server
                    File downloadFile1 `enter code`enter code here` here`= new File("/storage/sdcard1/a/new.jpg");// Path of my device
                    try {
                        ftp = new FTPClient();
                        ftp.connect(server, portNumber);
                        ftp.login(user, password);
                        ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                        ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                        OutputStream outputStream1 = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloadFile1));
                        boolean success = ftp.retrieveFile(remoteFile1, outputStream1);
                        System.out.println(success);
                        return true;
                    } finally {
                        if (ftp != null) {
                            ftp.logout();
                            ftp.disconnect();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Where is your catch block?

Comment: Oops I forgeted to add it, I will add it.

Comment: I have added catch block and now gives me this error  (java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard1/a/new.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied))

Comment: So this has nothing to do with ftp. Or downloading a file. Please adapt your post.